# how do I evaluate the critical points as it is the same as the end points of the interval it is defined in?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is f(x)=4x+sin(8x) in the interval {-π/6 <= x <= π/6} and I have to find out the interval for local max and min.

for f'(x) = 4+8cos(8x) and when f'(x) = 0 the values I got are: x= π/12, π/6,-π/6 and -π/12

I was able to find out what type of point π/12 and -π/12 is, but I do not know what to do for π/6 and -π/6. Do take the interval of (-∞,-π/6] and same for π/6? and see if there is a change in sign?